# how to check if an array contains the elements from a sub array

Tags: javascript

i want to check i an array contains the elements of any sub array, i.e.
`array1 = [10,11,12]`
`array 2 = [[10, 11],[20, 21],[30, 31],[40, 41]];`

array1 will be checked in series by each of array2's sub arrays and if the sub array elements are also in the array1 then to return true.

i've tried thing like:

```js
      array2.some((arr) => {
        return arr.every((square) => {
          return array1.includes(square);
        });
      });
```

or

```js
    for (let elem of array2) {
        if (elem.every((x) => array1.includes(x))) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }
```

any advice would be helpfull.
thank you

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Your snippet one looks okay. In the snippet two, in case of subarray match you are returning `false` which looks odd.

Comment: do you want to return `true` if you have `[11, 12]` in array2?

Comment: Are you trying to see if ***any*** of the items in `array1` exist in a sub-array of `array2`  or are you trying to see if ***all*** of them match a sub-array of `array2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the sub array as well for the sequence.

```js
const
    array1 = [10, 11, 12],
    array2 = [[10, 11], [20, 21], [30, 31], [40, 41]],
    result = array2.some(a => {
        for (let i = 0, l = array1.length - 1; i < l; i++) {
            if (a.every((v, j) => v === array1[i + j])) return true;
        }
        return false;        
    });

console.log(result);
```